# push items to two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I got this two dimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [parousia] => 
            [proforikos] => 
            [test] => 
            [ergasias] => 
            [telikos] => 
        )

)
```

And in a `for loop` I would like to add some more `null` items in the end of the array. Although I tried the following code:

```
            for ($i = 0; $i < $diff; $i++) {
              $array = array();
              $array['parousia'] = null;
              $array['proforikos'] = null;
              $array['test'] = null;
              $array['ergasias'] = null;
              $array['telikos'] = null;
              $finalarray = array_push($thearray, $array);
            }
```

Where `diff` is the number of the items and I want to add in the end of the array and `thearray` is the big array that is above at the code.

Although it seems legit and right, this `for loop` is not adding the items in the end of `thearray`.

Any idea or workaround?

Comment: Do you not want `$finalarray[] = $array;`?

Comment: How are you calling this, and if in a function, is the array passed in by reference? Or are you building a new array to return?

Comment: @MarkBaker the first big array, is the result of a query from codeigniter. Nothing much !

Comment: @JonStirling i want just to push items in the end of the first array.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios Perhaps provide an example of what output you're trying to get to.

Comment: what does `thearray` looks like? array_push is a void method I guess and doesn't return the new array

Comment: Forget about [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). It's an overrated function. Learn how to [create and modify array elements using the square brackets syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Comment: if `$diff` is 3, where do you want to add null item at the end ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// create inserted item
$item = array_fill_keys(['parousia','proforikos','test','ergasias','telikos'],null);
// make array with length equal  $diff, filled with $item 
$items = array_fill(0, $diff, $item);
// add them to $array
$array = array_merge($array, $items);
```

Comment: minor correction mate :) `$array_merge` -> `array_merge`, might confuse someone :D

Comment: Does php5.6 has the `array_fill_key` ?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios array_fill_keys - some typos . sorry :)

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios since 5.2 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php